# Upload file through HTML form, but file doesn't exist when debugging backend controller

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

This issue has been haunted me for several nights. I tried everything I could do but still no clue where is the cause...

I'm writing a simple file upload function based on `spring boot 1.5.4`, `spring webmvc 4.3.9`, `spring security 4.2.3`, `jQuery 3.3.1`, etc. (this is my github repo if you'd like to take a look at - https://github.com/pdsmyz1023/clndr)

My form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="/event/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- COMPONENT START -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose" type="button">Choose</button>
      </span>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" placeholder='Choose a file...' />
      <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Upload" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- COMPONENT END -->
</form>
```

My controller is (please ignore the method content or method return, since I only debug for the issue as of now):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public @ResponseBody
List<UploadedFile> uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Principal principal) throws IOException {
    try {

        Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = request.getFileMap();
        String userName = principal.getName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

My debugging screenshot is:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVqWo.png)

I cloned one tutorial from https://github.com/frenmanoj/dropzonejs-springmvc
and run on my local, everything is fine.

I compared the file upload http request, found my defected demo does not contain request payload and the request from the tutorial has request payload:

[from tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brR4T.png)

[from my defected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdHni.png)

Could you please help check why it happened? thanks a lot in advance!!!